# Possible to debug current tab in VSCode without editing launch.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, ecmascript-6

I often have multiple NodeJS scripts in the same project, and I can only get debugging in VSCode to work, if I edit the `launch.json` to point at a specific file.

Is there a way to have debug work in the current tab/file without first having to edit `launch.json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to create 1 run configuration for each app that you have, but once you have them, you can just pick the right app from a drop-down

[image]